# How to Document and correct indentation on apex

Tags: code

How can I automatically correct the indentation of my apex classes on Visual Studio Code?? I installed the Uncrustify extension but it is not working.

Also is there any way to document my methods automatically with visual studio?? With "document" I mean:

```
@Author
@params
@Description
```

In Eclipse there is a function that enables to select the method and it gives you an automatical way to do this.

Comment: You might get better answers on the [vs-code tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) on stack overflow.

Answer (score 5):

While I know some folks are happily and successfully using `uncrustify`, the formatting route that's currently recommended with the Visual Studio Code Extension Pack for Salesforce is Prettier.

The setup for Prettier on Apex is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/prettier/) as part of the user guide for the extension pack. I've used it to a limited extent with success.

Answer (score 4):

## Uncrustify

It only works if you enable an override (by default, it works on other languages). I found this [blog post](https://medium.com/@taxnexus/salesforce-apex-beautified-in-vs-code-with-uncrustify-7d0cbfc5ea1a) that explains more. You need to create a configuration file (`uncrustify.create`), then include the following settings:

```
{    "uncrustify.langOverrides": {
        "apex": "JAVA"
    }
}
```

## Auto-Generate Documentation

You can use [Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) to create your own documentation patterns, or install one from, say, Java, and configure it to work with Apex as well.

## ApexDoc

You can use [ApexDoc](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/ApexDoc) to generate documentation for your code, just as you would in Java.

Comment: n.b ApexDoc is unmaintained and is known not to work for some projects.

Comment: @DavidReed I couldn't find an updated version of it; if you know where it went off to, I'd be glad to reflect that in my answer.

Comment: As far as I know, nobody is maintaining it at this point. I'd be delighted to be wrong.

Comment: In a chat with Chris Peterson, back in January this year, he said "we are taking a look at making a new ApexDoc tool that's based off the real Apex compiler, rather than an attempt to reverse engineer it. There's an early prototype internally, but I don't have a timeline for when it will be available more generally".

Comment: @PhilW Cool stuff. Hopefully we get it soon, it's been about 13 years late, if you ask me.

Comment: Just stumbled across a new implementation of apexdoc on npm; it generates markdown instead of HTML which is a nice touch.  Haven't tried it yet, but will be shortly:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cparra/apexdocs