# How to add Class Summary to Apex Class with detailed descriptions of methods, signature, constructors etc?

Tags: apex, setup

Here is an example of created Class Summary in a managed package.
But I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

[image]

Comment: it is created automatically and visible for global classes in managed package.

Comment: And unfortunately doesn't pull in the apexdoc you may have authored. I had a conversation with Chris Peterson (apex PM at Salesforce) on this a couple of years ago, but not heard of any activity in this area since. Take a look back [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295693/how-to-document-and-correct-indentation-on-apex/295696?noredirect=1#comment442986_295696)

Comment: Feel free to upvote [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000N8pbVUAR/use-apexdoc-to-populate-autogenerated-global-api-documentation).